# Groups with abelianization $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

Are there any groups (besides $\mathbb{Z}$ itself) which have $\mathbb{Z}$ for their abelianization?

That is, is there any non-abelian group $G$ such that $G/[G,G] \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

I would appreciate some examples (if yes) or some hint as to why not (if no).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take your favorite group $G$ whose abelianization is trivial.  For example, $G=A_5$ works.  Then $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ has abelianization $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: And none of these looks like those in Mariano's examples.

Comment: (Except $\mathbb{Z}$ itself, that is!)

(Sorry - couldn't resist!)

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 10):

All [knot groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_group) have $\mathbb Z$ as abelianization.

That gives a nice supply of examples.

Comment: And none of these looks like those in Jason's examples.

Comment: (Except $\mathbb Z$ itself, that is!)

Comment: This actually prompted the question—a friend and I were discussing why knot complements are supposed to be interesting.  We convinced ourselves that $H_1$ must always be $\mathbb{Z}$ (with some Mayer-Vietoris.) Then we wondered if $\pi_1$ is interesting, but couldn't come up with any non-abelian groups with abelianization $\mathbb{Z}$.  Knowing that they're called knot groups will probably help!

Comment: There is a very simple way to get a presentation from a knot diagram (there are a few, in fact): you can simply draw a not and compute the so called Wirtinger presentation of the fundamental group. That way you can get lots of examples.